# Es6 generators: i += yield i;

Tags: javascript, generator

So this code was published on same places before as an example of generators in es6:

```
function *addGenerator() {
  var i = 0;
  while (true) {
    i += yield i;
  }
}

var gen = addGenerator();
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next(3).value);
console.log(gen.next(5).value);
```

Which gives: `0, 3, 8`.

What I don't get is why this `+= yield i` works. I guess it's because we wait until we get the next value, and if you pass something in `next()` it's an implicit return. So far so good. But why is the name of the var `i`?

If I do:

```
function *addGenerator() {
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  while (true) {
    i += yield j;
  }
}
```

It does not work, so there is something special about that var... Who knows?

Comment: In second example you'll get `0 0 0` as an output, because `gen.next().value` is the value of `j` variable - and this is `0` - you don't assign to it in a loop.

Comment: Ah figures, but how does passing the value of next() into the generator work?

Comment: It's returned from `yield`.

Comment: So it looks more or less like this: `var passedToNext = yield returnThisAsNext_value;` ;)

Comment: Alright, yeah, completely clear to me now. I should drink more coffee. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In second example you'll get `0 0 0` as an output, because `gen.next().value` is the value of `j` variable - and this is 0 - you don't assign to it in a loop.

General form of `yield` keyword can be seen as something like:

```
var passedToNext = yield returnThisAsNext_value;
```